# Difficulty in ending calls and going back to the MainActivity

Tags: android, telephonymanager

So I am building this phone app. From `MainActivity` it calls another Activity `phoneActivity` with people's names and when you click on one name it will pull up the phone app with that persons phone number. I would like to have it go back to the main activity after the call is terminated. I am stuck there. I think the reason is that I do not end the acitvity after the call finishes or the sort.

I do see that it goes to OFFHOOK in the logs. Would I need to terminate the activity after the call's end and if so how?

```
public class PhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent dialIntent;
//need to keep track coz first state is IDLE
boolean offHook = false;
String[] initialItems =  {"Zod","Lida"};
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

/* Check the Phone State to move back to the calling page */
private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        int prevState = state;
        Log.i("State of Call: ", Integer.toString(state));

        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i("PHONE ", "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i("PHONE ", "OFFHOOK"); // I see this in logs, what needs to be done here?
            //phone has passed the inital state
            offHook = true;
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
            Log.i("PHONE ", " Enter IDLE");
            //finish();
            if((prevState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Log.i("PHONE", "prev OFFHOOK " + Integer.toString(state));
                prevState=state;
                //Answered Call which is ended
                finish();
            }
            if((prevState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)){
                Log.i("PHONE", "prev RINGING " + Integer.toString(state));
                prevState=state;
                //Rejected or Missed call
            }
            /*
            if ( offHook ) {
                //finish();
                Log.i("PHONE","IDLE OFFHOOK");
                Intent goBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                //Initial phone state is false
                offHook = false;
                startActivity(goBack);

            } */
        }
    }
}

public void openDialer(String person) {
    Log.i("openDialer: ", "inside opendialer");
    //Uri u = Uri.parse("tel:" + "xxxxxxxxx");
    Uri u = Uri.parse("tel:" + map.get(person));
    dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,u);
    //dialIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    PhoneActivity.EndCallListener callListener = new PhoneActivity.EndCallListener();
    TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    startActivity(dialIntent);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);
    /*
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Zod","+88888888888");
    map.put("Lida","+140888888888");
    final List<String> myList =  map;
    */
    map.put("Zod","+18188888888");
    map.put("Lida","+14088888888");

    final List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(initialItems);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList){
    //ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList){
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Cast the listView each item as textView
            TextView item = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // Set the item text style to bold
            item.setTypeface(item.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            // Set size to 36
            item.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 36);
            return item;
        }
    };
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("Item clicked: ", myList.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Calling " + myList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            openDialer(myList.get(position));
           //System.out.println( myList.get(position) );
        }
    });
    TextView textViewEdit = findViewById(R.id.textViewEdit);
    textViewEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialer("Dummy");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()` after `startActivity(dialIntent);` will close your `phoneActivity` and go back to your `MainActivity`.